# Cannot retrieve google map marker coordinates from ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I'm trying to fetch markers from a mysql database using ajax call, but the markers are not showing up.

Here is my connect.php(ajax call connect.php)

```
<code>
<?php

$dbname            ='u769748933_tr'; //Name of the database
$dbuser            ='u769748933_ta'; //Username for the db
$dbpass            ='adamas'; //Password for the db
$dbserver          ='mysql.1freehosting.com'; //Name of the mysql server

$dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 'lat','lon' FROM poi_example");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
//Encode the $locations array in JSON format and print it out.
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($row);
?>
</code>
```

When I run connect.php it returns:

```
{"0":"lat","lat":"lat","1":"lon","lon":"lon"}
```

I don't know if this is valid.

Here is my javascript file containing the ajax call:

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Google Map API V3 with markers</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
 #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
 </style>
 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js'></script>


<script>
function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514980,-0.144328);
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 14,
center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);




    //When the Window finishes loading...
    $(window).load(function () {

        //Carry out an Ajax request.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'connect.php',
            success:function(data){
                //Loop through each location.
                $.each(data, function(){
                    //Plot the location as a marker
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(this.lat, this.lon); 
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>





<body style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
 <div id="map"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

below is my database picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsLgZ.png)

I've been struggling with this for 2 days!

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'connect.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
            ...
```

Or Alternatively:

```
success: function(data){
   data = $.parseJSON(data);
...
```

Also, Your $.each is incorrect, please make the following tweaks:

```
$.each(data, function(ind, val){
                    //Plot the location as a marker
                    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(val.lat, val.lon); 
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: pos,
                        map: map
                    });
                });
```

Also, you need to get your JSON as follows:

```
{"lat": "-73.899877", "lon" : "59.8765"}
```

For this you need to work upon your PHP code.

**PHP Code Changes**

```
$dbname            ='u769748933_tr'; //Name of the database
$dbuser            ='u769748933_ta'; //Username for the db
$dbpass            ='adamas'; //Password for the db
$dbserver          ='mysql.1freehosting.com'; //Name of the mysql server

$dbcnx = mysql_connect ("$dbserver", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die(mysql_error());
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 'lat','lon' FROM poi_example");
$result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    array_push($result, array(
        'lat' => $row['lat'],
        'lon' => $row['lon']
    ));
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the data your are receiving in success?
`console.log(data);` Also AJAX request is returning 200 status code?

Comment: any example to print the console?

Comment: inspect element will do the task for you. console.log(data) under success function. And check your console.

Comment: the php file is the culprit, its not printing as follows: {"lat": "-73.899877", "lon" : "59.8765"} any suggestion?

Comment: please share the database table pic

Comment: the picture is in the question itself at the botton

Answer (score 0):

When selecting fields in the sql you should use backticks - NOT single quotes! Also, whilst not tested, you might wish to retrieve the records row by row and assign the results to an array which you echo at the end for the javascript callback to use.

```
<?php

    $dbname            ='u769748933_tr'; //Name of the database
    $dbuser            ='u769748933_ta'; //Username for the db
    $dbpass            ='adamas'; //Password for the db
    $dbserver          ='mysql.1freehosting.com'; //Name of the mysql server

    $dbcnx = mysql_connect( $dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass );
    mysql_select_db( $dbname ) or die('unable to connect to database');

    $data=array();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `lat`,`lon` FROM `poi_example`");
    if( $query ){

        while( $rs=mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){
            $data[]=array( 'lat'=>$rs['lat'], 'lng'=>$rs['lng'] );
        }

    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```